# Getting the second root folder of current directory using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Let us consider that the current working directory of my script is

`/usr/src/app-directory/upload/try.sh`

In my script I need to echo `appdirectory` since is the second root folder of the script and also take note that I need to remove not alphanumeric strings. I was able to echo the root folder which is `upload`  with the code below

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$(basename $(pwd))"
```

and it returns

```
$ ./try.sh
upload
```

Comment: Your use of "root" is weird. I guess you really mean "parent". Your project's root (where the directory tree starts) is apparently `/usr/src/app-directory`

Comment: My apology but yes, I meant parent folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` might be easier:

```
var=$(awk -F'/' 'NF>2{print $(NF-1)}' <<<"$PWD" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g')
```

Prints the penultimate field (with `/` as the delimiter).

Comment: Sorry but how to make this into a variable? And how to exclude non-alphanumeric characters? Let's say the second to the root folder is `app-tri`, then I need to store into a variable with a value of `apptri`

Comment: Updated to to remove non alphanum chars and store the result in a variable.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, it would. That's what OP wanted as I understand.

Comment: @anubhava *If* `try.sh` is located in  `/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/infrastructure-playground/ci`
then OP wanted the last but one directory in the path which would be `infrastructureplayground` (after removing `-`).

Answer (score 1):

Using single `awk` command, you can do this:

```
s='/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/infrastructure-playground/ci'
var=$(awk -F/ 'NF>1{p=$(NF-1); gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]+/, "", p); print p}' <<< "$PWD")
echo "$var"
```

```
infrastructureplayground
```

Comment: The disadvantage of your script is it's not dynamic and will not stick to the `second root folder` if the directory is different like `/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/infrastructure-playground/ci/try,sh`. Your code will not echo `infrastructure-playground`